# name 'self' is not defined when in eval()

Tags: python-3.x

Dears,
I'm trying to run this code into an eval function, but i'm getting the error below:

> "name 'self' is not defined"

. Is there a way to avoid it without using global variables? Thanks!!!
This is basically the eval:

```
eval(sum(
                  sum(
                      self.dataset['Exposure'][c]
                      * self.suggested_decisions[c][d]
                      * int(self.constants['scaling_factor'] * self.decisions[d].variables[
                          'Recovery_Percentage_Segment_2'])
                      * self.dataset['Segment2'][c]
                      for c in self.all_records
                  )
                  for d in self.all_decisions
              )
)
```

To give a bit of context I'm putting here a simplified version of my code where I'm using the eval:

```
class Engine:
def __init__(self, xmlpath=None, timeout=30, expr=None):
    self.xml_path = xmlpath
    self.decisions = None
    self.dataset = None
    self.constants = None
    self.expr = expr
    self.load_problem(self.xml_path)
    self.num_records = len(self.dataset['ID'])
    self.all_records = range(self.num_records)
    self.all_decisions = range(len(self.decisions))
    self.suggested_decisions = {}
    self.timeout = timeout

def run(self):

    eval("recovered_amn_segment_1 ==" + self.Sum_ForAllRecordsAndDecisions(self.expr))

def Sum_ForAllRecordsAndDecisions(self, expr):


    return "sum(sum(" + expr + "for r in self.all_records) for d in self.all_decisions)"

def client():

expr = "self.suggested_decisions[r][d]*(self.dataset['Exposure'][r]*int(self.constants['scaling_factor'] * self.decisions[d].variables['Recovery_Percentage_Segment_1']*self.dataset['Segment1'][r]))"
xml_path = 'C:/Documenti/S1/Requirements/ottimizzatore/CollectionProblem.xml'
timeout = 30
engine = Engine(xml_path, timeout, expr)
engine.run()

client()
```

Basically from the client I'm passing a string "expr" to a class that manipulate the string and execute it. I hope it clarifies.

Thanks!!!

Comment: what should "self" have been in your original design? You should let python know what "self" is first. Although "self" is not keyword of python, in general, "self" is used as the first argument of a object method to indicate the object itself.

Comment: Because the eval is into a class that has variables self.dataset self.suggested_decisions...etc

Comment: Can you paste the method code? And please refer to eval function definition below:
eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])
The arguments are a string and optional globals and locals. If provided, globals must be a dictionary. If provided, locals can be any mapping object.

Comment: I've added a bit of context in the question. Onestly speacking it is not clear to me how to use eval with glocals/locals

Comment: You can pass custom `globals` into your call to `eval`, i.e. `eval("self.foo", {"self": self})`